# maven applying proxy to nonProxyHost

Tags: maven, proxy, maven-3

I have the following proxy set up in my settings.xml file

```
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>someusername</username>
  <password>somepassword</password>
  <host>some.proxy.host.com</host>
  <port>5150</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

But it still applies the proxy to my localhost, everytime I have to do something with localhost I have to change active to false.

Comment: When do you need to access your localhost through http through maven?

Comment: This is for Adobe CQ5. The CQ5 maven plugin needs to do this.

Comment: I have the same problem in maven 3.  I need to use the proxy to deploy to a tomcat server, but it's trying to use the proxy to talk to an internal Nexus repo.

Answer (score 6):

According to the docs[1] you can set

```
<useProxy>false</useProxy>
```

to prevent this from happening.

[1] http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html#Common%20Parameters

Comment: Doc link is out of date. Try this: https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/vlt-mavenplugin.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to deploy on localhost

try this

```
<nonProxyHosts>*localhost*</nonProxyHosts>
```

should work