# mave 3.2 not able to access local nexus instance return 502 code

Tags: maven, nexus

While accessing local nexus repository which is in local host the return code is 502.

pom.xml looks something like this

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>nexusPublic</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: This problem is not an issue in Maven it's an issue in your network. `502 Bad Gateway
The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server.` I assume your machine does not allow connections like that or nexus is not started or whatever.

Comment: I'm able to access same url from the browser.

Comment: That's not an argument, cause the browser is something different than Maven. Maven has it's settings in the settings.xml file where you should have to configure a proxy or whatever...I don't know if your are behind a proxy or how you configured your machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To OP and anyone who may have got here through google (just like me):

I had the same issue, the project I entered used some artifact from the repository on our server (via Archiva). I was able to reach the jar from browser, but Maven was not able to find it.

The problem was that my company uses proxy and it was impossible to connect to company's server through it's own proxy. I added `<nonProxyHosts>servername.dev.company.com</nonProxyHosts>` to my Maven configuration (.m2/settings.xml).
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25665040/2829378), in your case it would be `<nonProxyHosts>*localhost*</nonProxyHosts>`.

Answer (score 2):

Question is already answered but let me write full xml configuration file:

*.m2/settings.xml*

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>proxy_http</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy host</host>
      <port>porxy port</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|host_1|host_2|host_3</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```