# Unable to access nexus repo to download the dependencies

Tags: gradle, maven-2, nexus

I can see that the service is is hosted successfully.

[image]

My gradle script looks like this

```
group 'com.tinkering'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'


sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    //mavenCentral()
    maven{
        url 'http://linkxserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/'
      //url 'http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

}
```

When I am trying to run the gradle build, I am getting unknow host exception

```
$ ./gradlew clean build
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1.
  Required by:
      com.tinkering:gradletinker:1.0-SNAPSHOT
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1.
      > Could not get resource 'http://linkxserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'http://linkxserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.pom'.  Received status code 502 from server: internal error - server connection terminated
```

I did a curl on `http://linkxserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.pom` and getting the pom back.

I have setup the proxy server and I have the following repository configuration settings:

[image]

I followed exactly the same steps on my local machine and its working fine :-(

**UPDATE:** The Browse storage tab shows the pom's but not show any jar file downloaded.

[image]

Comment: put that url into a browser and see if you can download the pom file.

Comment: Curl'd and got the pom back as a response. I have updated the question with another snapshot.

Comment: I would check the configuration for the server and access cause `Received status code 502 from server: internal error ` this looks strange...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the proxy in your `setting.xml` and add

```
<proxy>
    <id> MyId </id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>yourAdress</host>
    <port>yourPort</port>
</proxy>
```

There is a similar issue on https://stackoverflow.com/a/26293538/7557036